# Python do_GET() how to perform action at the end of download process (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-get

I have my simple SimpleHTTPRequestHandler class with custom do_GET method. I am servicing normal fileserver operation, but additionally I added some methods to log events: GET_BEGIN, GET_END. Here is the code I am talking about:

```
class Http_transport_request_handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self._send_get_begin_event(path=self.path)
        super().do_GET()
        self._send_get_end_event()
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected GET_END has the same timing as GET_BEGIN. The question is. How to call custom method to have proper on_download_finished event for SimpleHTTPRequestHandler?

Comment: so `super().do_GET()` isn't blocking. You could wait for a return....

Comment: no, super().do_GET() is not blocking. It would be great to have some API method to wait for download finished or at least to overload some do_GET_finished() method.

Comment: well, an obvious hack is `time.sleep()`....ugly but effective on average....

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that connection is finished. It might be something like:
while downloading: time.sleep(0.1)

Comment: That's why it's a hack, on average you can make it correct through a **judicious** choice. Pick something that works on average and add a buffer to it. ugh.